# HDMI works only after restart

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I connect additional monitor to my laptop by HDMI. System detects second display only after restarting. 
`xrandr` command result without restarting computer:

```
 /$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1600x900       60.1*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

After restart when display works properly if I disconnect it system still think that additional diplay is connected and display some windows on the disconnected diplay so I have to restart computer.

I have Nvidia GeForce GT 120M

[image]

Any idea how to connect and disconnect HDMI without restarting computer?

Comment: Not a full-solution, but please know that technically all you need to do is restart X to get the desired results.  You can do this by simply logging out of your user and logging back in.  There may be a more elegant solution, but this is better than restarting your machine completely.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your help. I hope that there is a better solution.